# KDB Tickerplant Setup / Architecture with bid-matching-engine

Tags: kdb

I have a fairly default tickerplant setup running 
(data-mocking-process pushes to tickerplant, tickerplant is subscribed by RDB, EoD flush writes to HDB, gateway process queries RDB and HDB, etc.).

I now want to replace the data-mocking-process with a bid-matching-engine. 
This process needs realtime access to tables like quotes, orders, trades and additional user/accounting data tables.

**My questions** now are the following:

- I want to put the tables necessary for the bidmatcher into the RDB and populate them via `.u.upd` through the tickerplant. Is this the right approach? Or should I keep the tables local to the bidmatcher process?
- Is it safe to query the RDB for data from the bidmatcher (synchronously)?
- If I put the tables in the RDB and populate them via the tickerplant, how can I manage upserts? 
  `.u.upd` only does inserts and I cant find any example implementation that is `upsert` or `delete` -compatible.

Answer (score 3):

There are significant advantages in using the tickerplant to pass data to the RDB rather than having a standalone bidmatcher process. This allows for other subscribers to receive bidmatcher data if your setup changes in future and the tickerplant will create logs which will save and replay data if the RDB crashes.

Using synchronous queries to the RDB will work as it is only intraday data but if you are storing vast amounts of data per day then you may notice the RDB locking up temporarily as it runs your query. An alternative would be to use asynchronous queries, this way it doesn't block on the handle as it waits to return the result.

If are passing data into the tickerplant then the schema must be defined inside it which will then be read into your RDB so the schema is the same there.  If you are using a keyed table as a record then it will fail as the first column after the keyed column is expected by the tickerplant to be a time column. In a typical kdb+ tick setup the `.u.upd` function uses `16=type first first x;` which checks the column after the keyed column, if the record happens to be a keyed table then this fails when it reaches `(enlist(count first x)#a),x` in the same function. 
To get around this you will have to modify your upd function to include a check for "type first x=99h".  This way it can branch off and handle upserting appropriately for your data.